# ConstraintLayout Editor Biased

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've been trying to make a GUI for my app (using ConstraintLayout) where I have images that act like buttons aligned, however, those buttons (or anything actually) have this weird issue where even if I move (and save) the constraint position, it just goes back to some number (in this case 16).

What am I doing wrong here? What causes this/Why is the editor resetting the position?

[http://i.imgur.com/OFndFb7.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/OFndFb7.gifv) (GIF - 40s)

Versions:

- ConstraintLayout for Android - v 1.0.2
- Android Studio - 2.3.3 #AI-162.4069837

XML for the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Color_Red"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_red_color_menu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Color_Indigo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_indigo_color_menu"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Button_Color_Yellow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Color_Green"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_green_color_menu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Button_Color_Indigo"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_Color_Yellow"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_yellow_color_menu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Button_Color_Red" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML for btn_x_color_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/Red_Primary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: If you look in the XML, are the margins changing back to 16dp there too?

Comment: Yep, `android:layout_marginStart="16dp"`

Comment: Hm. I'm stumped... I never use the Design tab, so I'm not super familiar with its quirks.

Comment: Looks like the preview there is correct if I modify the XML (manually) and then go back there, however, if I click anything on that editor it does it again.

Comment: Post your XML and versions of ConstraintLayout and Android Studio.

Comment: Edited with the requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two attributes on the button `Button_Color_Green` that are in conflict.

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
```

The designer creates `android:layout_marginLeft` when you move the button, but `android:layout_marginStart` remains unchanged and in conflict. That is why the margin reverts after you move the widget.

These two attributes should be the same for a left-to-right layout, but the designer seems to want to change `android:layout_marginLeft` but honors `android:layout_marginStart` if it is present.

This may be a bug in `ConstraintLayout` 1.0.2. Until a fix or better solution is found, you can just manually change these attributes to be the same or just use `android:layout_marginLeft` and manually add `android:layout_marginStart` back in at a later time. (Lint should remind you to do this.)

Now that you know the issue, you may be able to work out a better solution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good catch. If you can target API 17+, just write `android:layout_marginStart` and drop `android:layout_marginLeft`.