# Constraint layout occasionally ignores changes to margins

Tags: android, user-interface

I am working on an Activity using a constraint layout. Every once in a while, when I try to increase the margins on one of my views, the changes seem to be ignored. I change the margin in the android studio ui, and the change briefly takes effect, but when I move focus to somewhere else on the activity, it shrinks back to the old distance, while keeping the new number. The change appears in the xml layout, but when run in the emulator, it doesn't render. This can usually be fixed by deleting and recreating the view.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like someone else had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356472/constraintlayout-editor-biased

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep my eye on that one. Hope this is fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but if you have two layout margin attributes of the same direction, like layout_marginLeft and layout_marginStart, sometimes the changes in the design tab only changes one of them, and it defaults to the other, so you have to change both manually in the xml file.

Comment: Hmm, next time it happens I'll check if that is the case. I think I was just using layout_MarginLeft though.